# console text to csv file- TypeError: write() argument must be str,

Tags: python, pandas

Any advice is much appreciated.  I returned some text to the console and I want to save the string as a csv file. I have tried a couple different ways to save it to no avail. One of the other ways that I have tried is turning the output into an array but that did not work either. If you have thoughts about returning console text to csv file please let me know thank you.

```
import os
from pdfminer3.layout import LAParams, LTTextBox
from pdfminer3.pdfpage import PDFPage
from pdfminer3.pdfinterp import PDFResourceManager
from pdfminer3.pdfinterp import PDFPageInterpreter
from pdfminer3.converter import TextConverter
import io
from PyPDF2 import PdfFileMerger, PdfFileReader

class Transform:
    #method for extracting data and merging it into one pdf

    def __init__(self):
        try:
            source_dir = os.getcwd()
            merger = PdfFileMerger()
            for item in os.listdir(source_dir):
                if item.endswith("pdf"):
                    merger.append(item)
        except Exception:
            print("unable to collect")
        finally:
            merger.write("test.pdf")
            merger.close()

#running that method extract
    def extract(self):
        resource_manager = PDFResourceManager()
        file = io.StringIO()
        converter = TextConverter(resource_manager, file, laparams=LAParams())
        page_interpreter = PDFPageInterpreter(resource_manager, converter)

        with open('test.pdf', 'rb') as fh:
            for page in PDFPage.get_pages(fh,
                                          caching=True,
                                          check_extractable=True):
                page_interpreter.process_page(page)

            text = file.getvalue()

        # close open handles
        converter.close()
        file.close()
        return text

    # def convertoarry(self, text):
    #     listToPrint = []
    #     for text in dict.keys():
    #         listToPrint.append(text)
    #         listToPrint.append(dict[text])
    #     stringToPrint = ",".join(listToPrint)
    #     return stringToPrint
    #
    #     stringToPrint = convertoarry(self, text)
    #     print(stringToprint)

    def modify(self, text):
        words = text.split()
        combine = [words.index()]
        with open("text.csv", "w") as f:
            f.write(combine)
            f.close()
            return "compeleted"


program = Transform()
print(program.modify())
```

Comment: The argument of the write function of yours is an array, not a single string that’s what seems to be the error.

Answer (score 1):

I assume the error you got comes from this line:

```py
            f.write(combine)
```

`combine` is a `list` object, while the `write` method of `f` wants a `str` object. This is what you should do:

```py
            f.write(str(combine))
```

Since you're creating a csv however, it is likely that you don't want the "[" and "]" in your file. Furthermore, by doing it like this, you will also include the "'" in your file, which it is likely you don't want. The safest way is simply to iterate over `words` rather than creating `combine`:

```py
    def modify(self, text):
        words = text.split()
        with open("text.csv", "w") as f:
            f.write(words[0])
            for word in words[1:]:
                f.write(f", {word}")
            f.close()
            return "compeleted"
```

By the way, you dont' need to explicitely close the file if you're working with a context manager (that is, if you use `with`). Hence you can simplify this code as follows:

```py
    def modify(self, text):
        words = text.split()
        with open("text.csv", "w") as f:
            f.write(words[0])
            for word in words[1:]:
                f.write(f", {word}")
        return "compeleted"
```

Comment: Thank you for provide that clarification on closing the file. I try to write clean code but I know that will come with practice.  the error I receive is a type error. TypeError: modify() missing 1 required positional argument: 'text'. I have passed text into the modify method so i am not sure what I am missing. I think i am missing a step with how I am implementing my program/

Comment: I don't see where you call the `modify` method in your code. However, it is high-likely that you didn't call this method from an instance of the `Transform` class. In order to call it, you should do something like `program = Transform()` and then `program.modify(text)`. If you want to call the `modify` method without instantiating, then you can add the `@staticmethod` decorator to the `modify` method, remove the `self` argument of this method, and then call it like this: `Transform.modify(text)`

Comment: Ah your right excuse my error. I have tried a bunch of stuff to make it work. I have corrected the error in my question. my ide wants me to set text = to something and I am not sure what as words is what I want to have modified.

Comment: Well, you have to pass some text to the `modify` method, like `transform.modify("Some text")` for instance. I'm not sure you understand what you're doing actually.

Comment: fair point. what I am trying to pass into the modify method is the variable text that I extracted from the previous methods.

Comment: Well then you just have to write `text = transform.extract()` and then `transform.modify(text)`, or directly `transform.modify(transform.extract())`

Comment: I think that is my problem. I was thinking that because this method was a child to the class transform it was taking all the previous variables. but i need didn't realize I realize I needed to create a new variable that initiates those methods then use that variable to do additional methods on said variable. Thanks!